# Spurious roots - graphical reason for invalidity

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations, analytic-geometry, roots, conic-sections

A question goes;

> Two parabolae have the same focus. If that their directrices are the x-axis and y-axis respectively, then find the slope of their common chord.

To solve it, you write out the general equations
$$(x-a)^2=4(\frac{1}{2}b)(y-\frac{b}{2}) \\(y-b)^2=4(\frac{1}{2}a)(x-\frac{a}{2})$$
Where a and b are constants.

Subtracting these give you $x^2-y^2=0$, or $(x+y)(x-y)=0$.

It can be shown that at one time, two parabolae satisfying these properties can only intersect at two points. So the slope of the common chord is either 1 or -1, as obtained just above.

The problem is, that seems to be a result that should depend on the signs of a and b. I played around with [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mnuqrx825p) applet for a while, and that's how it plays out.

If I had a specific a and b, say 3 and 5, the solution would have one spurious root; $x+y=0$. But I can't work out a reason for why I would get that root too when I carry out the same steps with these two specific parabolae. Similarly, negative values of a and b would mean $x-y=0$ is a spurious root.

How exactly do these invalid roots end up in this analysis? A correct, rigorous treatment would work out so that the result you obtain specifies each root to be valid in specific intervals of a and b, as they are. Where did I mess up in my attempt here?

Comment: There are no spurious roots here.  Instead, you only solved $\Gamma_1-\Gamma_2=0$ and not the full $\Gamma_1=\Gamma_2=0$, which is why you have the ambiguous $x=\pm y$.

Comment: @user10354138: is this about cases where $\Gamma_1=\Gamma_2 \neq 0$, and therefore $\Gamma_1-\Gamma_2=0$ but the point does not lie on either curve? I've thought about that, but the general method I've seen for obtaining lines that pass through the intersection points of multiple conics is taking the difference of their equations, which is why I did so, too. So that's wrong, and the stronger $\Gamma_1=\Gamma_2=0$ is to be used at all times for this purpose instead. Is that so?

Comment: If the difference were the equation of a line then you would have no problem. But it is the equation of a pair of lines, and cannot thus give you the answer: you must combine it with the original equations.

Comment: @harry For a simpler example consider the system $x=1, y=1$. Quite obviously, it has the unique solution $x=y=1$, but if you subtract the equations you get a whole "solution set" $x=y$. In general, equations $A=0, B=0$ are equivalent to $A=0, A-B=0$, but not with just $A-B=0$.

Comment: I have had a look at your Desmos graphics: why have you taken the very particular case where the focus has equal coordinates ($x=y=1$) ? What prevents you to take coordinates $x=1, y=3$ for example ? In this case the parabolas will not have the same shape...

Comment: @JeanMarie: the focus is determined by the values of a and b, which can be adjusted by the slider.

Comment: @dxiv: thanks, this and intelligentipauca's comments fix it. But I don't know how to get anything more from $A=0, A-B=0, ($and obviously$ B=0)$. How do I solve these?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca: can it be said that for higher-degree equations like these, where you can't simply cancel out terms by subtracting them as in linear equations, solving equations by substitution of variables is the best way forward? Doing so would make sure that both the initial equations hold true (which isn't done when you *just* subtract the equations). I haven't seen this pointed out as a comparison between substitution and elimination, which is why I ask.

Comment: If the difference of two equations has the same degree as the original equations and includes all the unknown, then it can rarely be of help. In the case at hand substitution of variables is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The number of constants in the equations can be reduced a little bit:

\begin{align}
(x-a)^2 &= b(2y - b), \\
(y-b)^2 &= a(2x - a).
\end{align}

We can also write the equations:

\begin{align}
(x-a)^2 + b^2 &= 2by, \\
(y-b)^2 + a^2 &= 2ax.
\end{align}

Assuming $a\neq 0$ and $b\neq 0,$ the left hand sides of the last two equations are positive, and therefore $x$ has the same sign as $a$ and $y$ has the same sign as $b.$

If $a$ and $b$ have the same sign, then so do $x$ and $y$
and it is not possible that $x + y = 0.$
Therefore the equation $x^2 - y^2 = 0$ is solved only when $x - y = 0.$

If $a$ and $b$ have opposite signs, then so do $x$ and $y$
and it is not possible that $x - y = 0.$
Therefore the equation $x^2 - y^2 = 0$ is solved only when $x + y = 0.$

Graphically, since $x$ must have the same sign as $a$ and $y$ must have the same sign as $b,$ any point $(x,y)$ that is at an intersection of the parabolas must be in the same quadrant as $(a,b).$

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer not slope=1?  There should be infinite answers for x and y at intersection points since there are an infinite number of equations that satisfy the conditions.  A slope of 1 intuitively makes sense as well considering the question is forcing symmetric vertices across the y=x (or y=-x) line along with perpendicular directrices.

Edit: The slope could very well be -1; depending on which quadrant the focus lies in.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).